# Hadith of Abu Huraira throat being cut?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation

Narrated By Abu Huraira: I have memorized two kinds of knowledge from Allah's Apostle . I have propagated one of them to you and if I propagated the second, then my pharynx (throat) would be cut (i.e. killed). [Sahih Bukhari, Vol 1, Book 3, Hadith #121]

https://sunnah.com/bukhari/3/62

What is the interpretation of this hadith from the scholars, why would Abu Huraira get his throat cut for with holding knowledge that was taught to him by Prophet Muhammad (s)?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He propagated the Hadith about religious matters but was cautious in sharing the *prophecies* about the [fitnah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Fitna) (tribulations) that occured during the times of Caliph Uthman, Caliph Ali and more importantly in the Umayyad caliphate of [Muawiyah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muawiyah_I) and [Yazid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yazid_I).

Obviously he would have been executed for treason if he had spoken against the Umayyad Caliphs.

The Umayyads led a revolt during the Caliphate of Ali, slaughtered several Sahabah(Companions of the Prophet(p.b.u.h)), laid siege to Makkah(caused damage to the Kaabah) and Medinah, and established a hereditary monarchy to replace the caliphate.

Reference: https://islamqa.info/en/147659

Comment: Is there anything but speculation to back this up?

Comment: @G. Bach This is what the majority scholars interpret (as asked in the question). If you are asking whether Abu Hurairah himself mentioned any details at all then no he didn't.